# How should I delete nested relationships?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

a newbie question:
How should I define the delete function in my dao for nested relationships?
For instance, I want to delete a specific workout with all it's corresponding exercises and trainings sets.
these are my entities:

```
@Entity(tableName = "workouts")
data class Workout(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo("workout_id")
    val workoutId: Long = 0,
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "set_count")
    val setsCount: Int,
)

@Entity(tableName = "exercises")
data class Exercise(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo("exercise_id")
    val exerciseId: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo("workout_id")
    val workoutId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo("exercise_name")
    val exerciseName: String

)

@Entity(tableName = "training_sets")
data class TrainingSet (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo("training_set_id")
    val trainingSetId: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo("exercise_id")
    val exerciseId: Long,
    val weight: Int,
    val repetitions: Int
)

data class ExerciseWithTrainingSets(
    @Embedded
    val exercise: Exercise,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "exercise_id",
        entityColumn = "exercise_id"
    )
    val trainingSets: List<TrainingSet>
)

data class WorkoutWithExercisesAndSets(
    @Embedded
    val workout: Workout,
    @Relation(
        entity = Exercise::class,
        parentColumn = "workout_id",
        entityColumn = "workout_id"
    )
    val exercisesWithTrainingSets: List<ExerciseWithTrainingSets>
)
```

I tried to do something myself but I dont think it is the most eficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define **Foreign Key constraints** and utilise the **cascade** option of the **on delete** action; doing so would automatically cascade deletions to children on your behalf.

That is you use the `foreignKeys` parameter of the `@Entity` annotation and utilise the `onDelete` parameter of the respective ForeignKey to define the CASCADE option.

As an example an Exercise appears to be a child of a Workout so you could have:-

```
@Entity(tableName = "exercises",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            Workout::class,
            parentColumns = ["workout_id"],
            childColumns = ["workout_id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class Exercise(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo("exercise_id")
    val exerciseId: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo("workout_id", index = true) /* Added Index as may be more efficient and to suppress warning */
    val workoutId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo("exercise_name")
    val exerciseName: String

)
```

- Note that this implements a rule that an Exercise MUST have an existing parent Workout i.e. it enforces Referential Integrity.
- If a row is deleted from the workouts table then all rows in the exercises that reference the workouts row.
- the `onDelete` can also be specified with CASCADE, this will apply a change to the referenced value in the workouts table to the value in the exercises table.

Likewise you could doe the same for the TrainingSet class (training_sets table) where an Exercise is a parent e.g.:-

```
@Entity(tableName = "training_sets",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            Exercise::class,
            parentColumns = ["exercise_id"],
            childColumns = ["exercise_id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class TrainingSet (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo("training_set_id")
    val trainingSetId: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo("exercise_id", index = true)
    val exerciseId: Long,
    val weight: Int,
    val repetitions: Int
)
```

- Note that `onUpdate` has been included to demonstrate it's inclusion.

In both examples the field that references the parent has been made to have an index. This is not necessary but can improve efficiency and it also suppresses the warning about a full table scan.

If both of the above are used then the deletion of a row in the workouts table will both deleted the children in the exercises table AND the children of that exercises i.e. it conforms to the hierarchy of the relationships.

As such everything is done in a single transaction and thus probably the most efficient way possible (especially I believe with the suggested additional indexes).

- Note that maintaining an index does incur additional resource usage so inserts into the exercises and training_sets tables will be a little less efficient but typically this is compensated for by more efficient access to the related data.